# touch command in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm rather new to this server-config stuff.

I'm following the ubuntu tutorial on [OpenSSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) and I came across the command `echo '01' > serial  && touch index.txt` and i'm not quite sure what it's doing.  I read something about 'touch' doing something with a timestamp.

What does the `touch filename.txt` command do exactly?

It seems to send me into some weird prompt that I do not know how to get out of.

Comment: An example of the "weird prompt" would be useful.

Comment: Weird prompt is almost certainly the PS2 secondary prompt, as kaerast diagnosed.

Comment: kaerast was in fact correct.  After entering the command it would return to a new line with a >.  Thanks for being understanding - I'm venturing into the unknown with this server stuff!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The weird prompt will be because you aren't closing the quotation marks properly - try typing in rather than copy/pasting, on some websites the quotation marks are converted into pretty ones rather than ones which are usable in the shell.

`touch filename.txt` will set the last modified time of filename.txt to the current time and, if the file didn't already exist, will create it (presuming you have permissions to do all that of course).